# Create a simple cylinder using command-line FreeCAD

Tags: python, freecad

I would like to create a simple pillar in FreeCAD using python and the export it as .stl file

[image]

What have I done so far?

1. Recorded a macro of me creating a cylinder (Part) and exporting it as an stl file.

   [image: der]
2. I copy and paste the text from the macro into a python file, which I named "pillar.py"

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
import FreeCAD
import Part
import Mesh


App.ActiveDocument.addObject("Part::Cylinder","Cylinder")
App.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Label = "Cylinder"
App.ActiveDocument.recompute()

__objs__=[]
__objs__.append(FreeCAD.getDocument("Unnamed").getObject("Cylinder"))
Mesh.export(__objs__,u"C:/Users/totyped/Desktop/pillar_2.stl")

del __objs__
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

3. I closed the GUI and open the terminal, and I type:

   "C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\FreeCADCmd.exe" "C:\Users\totyped\Documents\pillar.py"

Source: https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=23869

**The result:** it just shows this on the terminal, but does not create any stl file.

[image]

It also does not give any warning or error message...

### Note

SO, I noticed that it will work, if I put the script file into the same directory as FreeCADmd.exe. Why ? I have no clue.

### Edit

So, as suggested by @sliptonic I tried to change the script file to:

```
import FreeCAD
import Part
import Mesh

App.newDocument("Unnamed")
App.ActiveDocument.addObject("Part::Cylinder","Cylinder")
App.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Label = "Cylinder"
App.ActiveDocument.recompute()

__objs__=[]
__objs__.append(FreeCAD.getDocument("Unnamed").getObject("Cylinder"))
Mesh.export(__objs__,u"pillar_2.stl")

del __objs__
```

but I still did not get any cylinder. Maybe the log file can help?
Here it is:

```
Msg: FreeCAD 0.18, Libs: 0.18R4 (GitTag)
(c) Juergen Riegel, Werner Mayer, Yorik van Havre 2001-2019
  #####                 ####  ###   ####  
  #                    #      # #   #   # 
  #     ##  #### ####  #     #   #  #   # 
  ####  # # #  # #  #  #     #####  #   # 
  #     #   #### ####  #    #     # #   # 
  #     #   #    #     #    #     # #   #  ##  ##  ##
  #     #   #### ####   ### #     # ####   ##  ##  ##

Log: Time = Wed Jan 22 10:17:07 2020
Log: AppDataSkipVendor = true
Log: AppHomePath = C:/Program Files/FreeCAD 0.18/
Log: AppTempPath = C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Temp\
Log: BinPath = C:/Program Files/FreeCAD 0.18/bin\
Log: BuildRepositoryURL = git://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD.git releases/FreeCAD-0-18
Log: BuildRevision = 4 (GitTag)
Log: BuildRevisionBranch = releases/FreeCAD-0-18
Log: BuildRevisionDate = 2019/10/22 16:53:35
Log: BuildRevisionHash = 980bf9060e28555fecd9e3462f68ca74007b70f8
Log: BuildVersionMajor = 0
Log: BuildVersionMinor = 18
Log: CopyrightInfo = (c) Juergen Riegel, Werner Mayer, Yorik van Havre 2001-2019
  #####                 ####  ###   ####  
  #                    #      # #   #   # 
  #     ##  #### ####  #     #   #  #   # 
  ####  # # #  # #  #  #     #####  #   # 
  #     #   #### ####  #    #     # #   # 
  #     #   #    #     #    #     # #   #  ##  ##  ##
  #     #   #### ####   ### #     # ####   ##  ##  ##


Log: Debug = 0
Log: DocPath = C:/Program Files/FreeCAD 0.18/doc\
Log: ExeName = FreeCAD
Log: ExeVendor = FreeCAD
Log: ExeVersion = 0.18
Log: LoggingFile = 1
Log: LoggingFileName = C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Roaming\FreeCAD\FreeCAD.log
Log: OpenFile0 = pillar.py
Log: OpenFileCount = 1
Log: PATH = C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\Library\bin;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NGX;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v94\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
Log: PythonSearchPath = C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\python36.zip;C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\DLLs;C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\lib;C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin
Log: RunMode = Exit
Log: SystemParameter = C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Roaming\FreeCAD\system.cfg
Log: UserAppData = C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Roaming\FreeCAD\
Log: UserHomePath = C:\Users\Henry\Documents
Log: UserParameter = C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Roaming\FreeCAD\user.cfg
Log: Verbose = 
Log: Create Application
Log: Run App init script
Log: Init: starting App::FreeCADInit.py
Log: Init:   Searching for modules...
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\AddonManager... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Arch... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Complete... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Draft... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Drawing... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Fem... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Idf... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Image... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Import... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Inspection... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Material... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Measure... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Mesh... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\MeshPart... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\OpenSCAD... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Part... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\PartDesign... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Path... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Plot(Init.py not found)... ignore
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Points... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Raytracing... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Robot... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Ship(Init.py not found)... ignore
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Show(Init.py not found)... ignore
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Sketcher... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Spreadsheet... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Start... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Surface... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\TechDraw... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Test... done
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Tux(Init.py not found)... ignore
Log: Init:      Initializing C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Web... done
Log: Using C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod as module path!
Log: System path after init:
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\AddonManager
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Arch
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Complete
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Draft
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Drawing
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Fem
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Idf
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Image
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Import
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Inspection
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Material
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Measure
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Mesh
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\MeshPart
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\OpenSCAD
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Part
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\PartDesign
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Path
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Plot
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Points
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Raytracing
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Robot
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Ship
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Show
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Sketcher
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Spreadsheet
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Start
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Surface
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\TechDraw
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Test
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Tux
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\Mod\Web
Log:    C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\Library\bin
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Library\bin
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\Scripts
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\bin
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\Anaconda3\condabin
Log:    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
Log:    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp
Log:    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Log:    C:\WINDOWS
Log:    C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Log:    C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
Log:    C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH
Log:    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin
Log:    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NGX
Log:    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v94\runtime\win64
Log:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript
Log:    C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Log:    C:\Users\Henry\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
Log: Init: App::FreeCADInit.py done
Log: Init: Processing command line files
Log: Init:     Processing file: pillar.py
Log: Exiting on purpose
Log: FreeCAD terminating...
Log: Saving system parameter...
Log: Saving system parameter...done
Log: Saving user parameter...
Log: Saving user parameter...done
```

It's weird because if I run is as a macro from within the FreeCAD GUI it works and creates the .stl cylinder.

Comment: I am not windows user but are the quotes needed for running freecad in the terminal?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi As far as I am concerned: Yes. When I try to do it without I get: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

You have commands to add objects to the activedocument and recompute but you don't actually have an document.  This works for me.  (minor changes for linux)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import FreeCAD
import Part
import Mesh

App.newDocument("Unnamed")
App.ActiveDocument.addObject("Part::Cylinder","Cylinder")
App.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Label = "Cylinder"
App.ActiveDocument.recompute()

__objs__=[]
__objs__.append(FreeCAD.getDocument("Unnamed").getObject("Cylinder"))
Mesh.export(__objs__,u"/home/brad/pillar_2.stl")

del __objs__
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately, it still does not work for me. Please have a look at my updated question, in which I also paste the log file. Maybe this can help spot the error...

Comment: It works for me using either the FreeCADCmd method or just directly calling the python file.  You could try adding some print('debug messages')  to the script and verify that the script is actually getting executed.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not print anything. I don't know what to do...

Comment: SO, I noticed that it will work, if I put the script file into the same directory as FreeCADmd.exe. Why ? I have no clue...

Comment: If nothing was printing, then it's unlikely the script was getting executed at all.  It's surprising that you didn't get a python exception about an unknown file.  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the workbench Part click on the cube icon Part Cylinder.png. The default is for a full cylinder to be positioned, the centre of one circular face coincident with the global origin (point 0,0,0), with a radius of 2mm and height of 10mm.

Comment: OP is asking how to accomplish his goal via Python, not the GUI.